# Passing variable with URL but not able to make decision with Switch statement

Tags: php

On page1.php, i use

```
<a href="page2.php?choice=<?php echo $value?> & item1=<?php echo $abs1?> & item2=<?php echo $abs2?>" title="Link to next page">Download</a>
```

On page2.php, i receive these variables correctly as iam able to echo those. But Switch statement doesn't work.

```
echo $_REQUEST["choice"];echo "<br>"; //printing variable to debug
echo $_REQUEST['item1'];echo "<br>";  //printing variable to debug
echo $_REQUEST['item2'];echo "<br>";  //printing variable to debug

switch((string)$_REQUEST["choice"]) {
    case "Value1":
            echo "Value 1 selected";
            break;
    case "Value2":
            echo "Value 2 selected";
            break;
    case "Value3":
            echo "Value 3 selected";
            break;
        default:
                                 echo "No Value selected";
    }
```

It always give:  **No Value selected** . Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what does printing `$_REQUEST["choice"]` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see the data you are receiving and also trim() value you are receiving.

```
switch(trim($_REQUEST["choice"])) {
    case "Value1":
            echo "Value 1 selected";
            break;
    case "Value2":
            echo "Value 2 selected";
            break;
    case "Value3":
            echo "Value 3 selected";
            break;
        default:
                                 echo "No Value selected";
    }
```

Comment: Thx Pheonix. It works perfectly.I was passing extra whitespace to the variables. Iam able to see variable with echo then will it make any difference using var_dump($_REQUEST)?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo $value?> & item1=<?php echo $abs1?>
                   ^ whitespace
```

better readability (tons of alternatives)

```
echo "<a href=\"page2.php?choice={$value}&item1={$abs1}&item2={$abs2}\" title=\"Link to next page\">Download</a>";
```

Comment: yup, and also there is no semicolon

Answer (score 2):

You have an URL like the following:

```
page2.php?choice=VALUE & item1=VALUE & item2=VALUE
```

I noticed some spaces in there (before and after the `&`), so your choice value will have a trailing space. Either [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the choice string, or remove the whitespaces from the URL.